# mod-auth-token setup with dynamic url

Tags: php, .htaccess, stream

im install mod-auth-token https://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-token/,
But im not sure that i can understant how to setup to working on my site

my site is on

```
site.com
```

my video url - example

```
http://cdn.site.com/videos/0613/0613558644/0613558644.flv
http://cdn.site.com/videos/0705/0705559716/0705559716.mp4
```

path

```
/home/username/public_html/cdn/videos/0613/0613558644.flv
```

mod_auth_token documentation say about config

**First we need to configure the apache server.**

```
<Location /downloads/>
      AuthTokenSecret       "secret string"
      AuthTokenPrefix       /downloads/
      AuthTokenTimeout      60
      AuthTokenLimitByIp    off
</Location>
```

If i can understand i need to change **AuthTokenPrefix** to something like this /videos/0613/0613558644/ but my problem is because url is not always same...

Its possible to use this mod for my site config and url structure?